# This code snippet is storing the value of input with a '\n' which is not letting it match with the other string with same input but without '\n'

Tags: c, gcc, file-handling

I am trying to match the input of a string by user with that of the string from a file. But there are two things that is not happening the right way.

```
typedef struct
{
    int yyyy;
    int mm;
    int dd;
} Date;

int main()
{
    FILE *fp2;
    fp2=fopen("StudentId.txt","r");

    char input[255];
    char *id;
    id = (char *)malloc(sizeof(Date));

    printf("Enter your UserId:\n");
    gets(id);
    gets(id);
    fgets(input,sizeof(input),fp2);
    int cmp;
    printf("%s_\n%s_\n",input,id );
    return 0;
}
```

Firstly I have to use two gets(id) instead of one as the program seems to skip the first one. Second, the after getting stored is printed as follows

```
Aditya828
_Aditya828_
```

Which makes me wonder why is it storing input with a '\n' and id not.
Is there any way to fix the issues?

Comment: First of all never ever use `gets`. It's a [*dangerous*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) function that has even been removed from the C standard. Secondly, `d = (char *)malloc(sizeof(Date));`? That makes no sense. `Date` is a structure of integers, `id` is a a pointer to `char` (which together with your use of it indicates it's a string). Those two are different things. Thirdly, you do `gets(id)` directly followed by `gets(id)`. What do you think will happen with that?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i have to use ```gets(id)``` twice because because the first one is skipped abruptly.

Answer (score 1):

> why is it storing `input` with a `'\0'` and `id` not.

This conclusion misinterprets the results.

Both `id` and `input` have a string terminating *null chracter* `'\0'`.
`input` also has `'\n'` as `fgets()` retains the line-feed.  `gets()` does not.

> Is there any way to fix the issues?

Avoid `gets()`.  It is [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2410359).

Instead use `fgets()` to read `id`.

Use a buffer sized based on the text represeatation of `id`, not the size of `Date`.  Be generous.

```
#define ID_MAX_SIZE 40    // Expected max size
char id[ID_MAX_SIZE * 2]; // Be generous.  Later code can trucate if needed.

if (fgets(id, sizeof id, stdin)) {
  id[strcspn(id, "\n")] = '\0'; // Lop off potential \n
  printf("id: <%s>\n", id);
}
```

Comment: whats the use of <%s>?

Comment: That's not ```<%s>```, that's this ```%s```. @aaks-ctrl
Later will be printed as ```id: <1234>```.

Comment: it did solve the '\n' issue, the ```gets``` that i had to use two times, i have to do the same thing with ```fgets```. Why do they dont function on being called once here?

Comment: @aaks-ctrl What is the length of `StudentId.txt` and what is its exact contents: best if you can provide a hexadecimal dump and ASCII.

Comment: @aaks-ctrl When printing text that _may_ have leading/trailing white-space, `"<%s>"` is more useful than `"%s"`.